# C arrays and null byte

Tags: c, arrays, null, int

I have a question for better understing how arrays and nullbytes work in C.

Let's say I have an int array of 13 cells.
Let's say I want cells number: 1, 2, 3 and 10 to have a value. The others that are left as default, automatically get the nullchar \0 as value ?

My understanding of \0 was that the nullbyte is always at the end of the array and its function is to tell the program where array ends. But seems to be wrong

I wrote a simple prog to verify that and seems it is like that:

```
int nums[13] = {1,2,3};
nums[10] = 69;
int i;
for(i=0;i<13;i++) {
    if(nums[i]=='\0') {
        printf("null char found! in position: %d\n",i);
    }
    else {
        printf("element: %d found in position: %d of int array\n",nums[i],i);
    }
}

return 0;
```

here is the output:

element: 1 found in position: 0 of int array

element: 2 found in position: 1 of int array

element: 3 found in position: 2 of int array

null char found! in position: 3

null char found! in position: 4

null char found! in position: 5

null char found! in position: 6

null char found! in position: 7

null char found! in position: 8

null char found! in position: 9

element: 69 found in position: 10 of int array

null char found! in position: 11

null char found! in position: 12

| 1 | | 2 | | 3 | | \0 | | \0 | | \0 | | \0 | | \0 | | \0 | | 69 | | \0 | | \0 | | \0 |

So why default cells are set with the \0 value ? instead of being left empty for example ?

Shouldn't the null char be just once at the end of the entire array ?
Thanks

Comment: Statically allocated memory is filled with 0 for scalars or NULL (\0) for pointers.  If you cast \0 as a scalar it will be converted to 0.  There is no such thing as "empty".  You shouldn't be comparing NULL (\0) to an int anyway, use a literal 0.

Comment: "My understanding of \0 was that the nullbyte is always at the end of the array .." is utterly wrong. You are confusing regular arrays and C strings.

Comment: @Tibrogargan `\0` (the NUL character) isn't the same as the `NULL`-pointer. `\0` is a byte with all bits set to 0, which would always compare equal to the `int` 0.

Comment: @Kninnug Yup, thanks for the correction.  I meant NUL.  Too many variants of NULL. null, nul, nil, NUL etc etc

Answer (score 3):

There is no requirement in C that *arrays* need a `\0` at the end. A NUL-terminator is only needed for C *strings* (which usually have the `char` or `wchar_t` or other *character* type). In a C string the `\0` byte also doesn't have to be at the end of the array that contains it, but it must be at the end of the string part. It is perfectly valid to have 0's anywhere within an array. But if that array is used as a string, then the standard C string functions will interpret the 0 with the lowest index to signify the end of the string.

When you declare a variable (`nums`) in C with an initializer (`{1,2,3}`) in

```
int nums[13] = {1,2,3};
```

all indexes that aren't mentioned in the initializer (3 through 12) have their value initialized to `0`. It is not possible to have 'empty' cells in an array. All cells will have a value, it is up to the program(mer) what values to consider empty.

Answer (score 2):

C types correspond to memory, and memory has no real concept of "empty". There are languages where everything (or almost) can be made "empty" by putting some "empty" constant (Python has `None`, for instance), but C doesn't allow that. One reason to not allow it is that it forces you to have a special universal pattern for the empty state, and this has low-level repercussions. For instance, a character can take any value from 0 to 255 inclusively. That's because characters occupy 8 bits. If you also wanted to have an empty state without sacrificing possible values for characters, you'd need at least one more bit since the 8 other bits can be used for legitimate reasons, and this is undesirable for a lot of reasons.

For your array, the initialization syntax that you're using sets every unspecified element to zero. If you write:

```
char foo[4] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
```

then every element has a value (notice that it has no null byte in the end, because arrays don't need to have a null byte in the end–however, if you're using them as strings, then they very much should). If you write:

```
char foo[4] = {1, 2};
```

elements 0 and 1 have a specified value, but 2 and 3 don't, and with this syntax C will assume that you want to make them zero. On the other hand, if you write:

```
char foo[4];
```

you are not assigning any value to any element, and in this case C will not initialize the array at all. It would be undefined behavior to read from it; in practice, usually, the elements will take the values of whatever happened to exist at its memory location previously.

Answer (score 0):

NULL defined as (void*)0 - 
It is zero with generic ptr casting,
wich is equal to the NUL character's (\0) ascii code - 0

Arrays do not need to end with any special character/number.

strings do need to end with a special character, and the reason is simple, it lets functions wich operates on strings "know" where the string ends , for example:

```
char str[100] = {'h','e','l','l','o',0}; // same as {'h','e','l','l','o','\0'}
printf("%s",str);
```

prints:
    hello

if the last character in the string was not NUL it will print 95 garbage characters after the string ("hello") because the array size is 100 and there is no way for the compiler to know where the string ends.

Even though the zero at the 6th cell is ending the string in most compilers you can set only the "hello" string and they will fill out the rest of the cells with zeroes, so it will be ok in both cases.

Comment: NUL (the name for the null character)  and `NULL` (the null pointer literal) are different kind of animals.

Answer (score -1):

First of all, you are confusing C strings with regular arrays.  With strings, there is always a `\0` at the end of the `char`array.  It signifies the end of the string.  For example, say you have this:

```
char myText[] = "hello";
```

In this case, the array places look like this:

```
    myText[0] = 'h';
    myText[1] = 'e';
    myText[2] = 'l';
    myText[3] = 'l';
    myText[4] = 'o';
    myText[5] = '\0';
```

However, arrays do not terminate with `'\0'`.  Take another example:

```
int myArray[3] = {1, 2, 3};
```

According to your rule, since arrays have to terminate with a `'\0'`, this is not a legal statement since we only give the array 3 elements instead of 4, and we would need 4 elements to include a `'\0'`.  However, this is a completely legal statement in C.  Clearly, space for the `'\0'` is not needed in arrays, just at the end of C strings.

Also note that `'\0'` is equivalent to the integer, as [Kninnug](https://stackoverflow.com/users/249237/kninnug) pointed out in the comments:

> `\0` (the null character) isn't the same as the NULL-pointer. `\0` is a byte with all bits set to 0, which would always compare equal to the int 0.

So, in your program, you could just equally check if:

```
if(nums[i] == 0)
```

Now, let's prove why you are getting your output.

> Shouldn't the null char be just once at the end of the entire array?

No.  Any other elements left empty will be initialized with the value of zero.  So that is why you are seeing the output that you have; elements that are not `num[0]`, `num[1]`, `num[2]`, or `num[10]` will be initialized with zero.  Since you are checking for `\0` (also `0`) then everything else with not those elements will be 0.

---

As [alk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/694576/alk) pointed out in the comments, the null character and the null pointer literal are different.  At the end of C strings, you see the null character (NUL) which is `'/0'` or 0.  However, the null pointer literal (`NULL`) is different.

Comment: Can anyone explain the down vote so I can improve the post?

Comment: NUL (the name for the null character)  and `NULL` (the null pointer literal) are different kind of animals.

Comment: A C-"string" is a character array with at least one of it's elements being equal to the NUL, the null-character (being equal to `'\0'` which is equal to  `0`). A character array not necessarily is a C-"string".

Comment: @alk Thank you for the correction.  Did my edit make the post more accurate?

Comment: "*First of all, you are confusing char arrays with regular arrays*" No, the guy is confusing strings with char-arrays.

Comment: @alk hmm...C strings _are_ char arrays.  Maybe I could have reworded the first statement better though.

Comment: "*strings are char arrays.*". Yesno, they are ***`0`-terminated*** `char`-arrays. And a `char`-array by itself isn't a string. It's just an array like an array of any other type.

Comment: @alk Oh, OK I see what you mean...but I don't think he/she is confusing char arrays with strings since the person is misunderstanding how to work with an array of `int`s.  Although I see your point...it would be more correct to replace every appearance of "char array" with "string" in the post.  Will do whenever I get the chance  (I am on mobile right now).

Comment: Yes, the OP projects the idea behind strings to other arrays, because the OP misunderstood the concept which makes a `char`-array a string. An array is a "type", a C-"string" isn't a "type" (as it is in many other languages), but in C it's a "data structure".

Comment: @alk I don't mind whoever down voted; the post conveyed misinformation.  I just want the post to be correct...that's why I carry on these conversations.  What good does a post do if it is left incorrect?